# wrong _WIN32_WININT value in visual studio 2012

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to compile a third party libary(Apache Ignite C++), but the compiliation failed on this error

> error C3861: 'SleepConditionVariableCS': identifier not found

This variable is defined in **synchapi.h**, and depends in the following condition

```
#if ((!defined(_CONTRACT_GEN) && (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)) || (_APISET_MINWIN_VERSION >= 0x0101))
```

I am using visual studio 2012 on Windows 7 and yet in my visual studio project properties I can see the following definition

[image]

As you can see I can't change it because it is inherited value.

So how can I change this macro in order to compile my code successfully?

And generally where is that macro defined? accoridng to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/using-the-windows-headers, this value is appropriate to Windows XP, so it seems strange considering I am on Windows 7.

Comment: There's a checkbox on the *"Inherit from parent project or defaults"* option. Untick it, and you can change preprocessor symbols all day long. There are other options, but that is probably the easiest. The value is defined in the project default template, that gets included into your .vcxproj file.

Comment: Besides that, Visual Studio *never* picks a target platform based on the platform you are compiling on. That's just not a logical thing to do, although it appears to be *very* common in the \*nix world. For whatever reason.

Comment: You inherited this macro setting from a project property sheet.  Not an accident, whomever created it wanted to ensure that this program could still run on XP/Win2003.  Use View > Other Windows > Property Manager to see it, press F1 to learn more about the feature.

Comment: Note that VS 2012's default Platform Toolset ``v110`` uses the Windows 8.0 SDK which **does not support targeting Windows XP**, so ``_WINNT_WIN32`` set to ``0x0600`` is the oldest meaningful value you can use in that case. To target Windows XP with ``0x0502``, you have to use the ``v110_xp`` Platform Toolset which uses a Windows 7.1A SDK. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1/)